# Convert SumIfs Excel Function to MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, excel

[image: Here is the solution in Excel with Data.]

The formula in cell G2 "ReplenQty" is:

```
=SUMIFS(D:D,A:A,A2,B:B,B2,C:C,">=" & E2,C:C,"<=" &F2)
```

The formula in cell H2 "RpInVar" is:

```
=IF($A2<>$A1,ROUND(VAR(IF($A:$A=$A2,$G:$G)),2),0)
```

I attempted this in MySQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
Part, 
Customer, 
OrdDt,
OrdQty,
StartDate,
ReplenDate,
SUM(CASE WHEN Part = Part AND Customer = Customer AND OrdDt >= StartDate AND OrdDt <= ReplenDate THEN OrdQty ELSE 0 END) AS ReplenQty,
VARIANCE(CASE WHEN Part = Part AND Customer = Customer AND OrdDt >= StartDate AND OrdDt <= ReplenDate THEN OrdQty ELSE 0 END) AS RpInVar,
FROM 
BeforeReplenQty
GROUP BY 
Part, 
Customer, 
OrdDt, 
OrdQty, 
StartDate, 
ReplenDate;
```

Problem is OrdQty and ReplenQty are the same and RpInVar are all 0.

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

This query is quite long and complicated but working on this demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b3334/70

One task is to do a sum where order date is between start date and replenish date.
Then get the row where part is new compared to previous row.

The first part of the query is to get the variance, the second subquery is to get the sum of Ordered qty and the sub-query at the bottom is to get the row where part column has changed.

```
select tab.Part,tab.Customer,tab.OrdDt,tab.OrdQty,tab.StartDate,tab.ReplenDate,tab.ReplenQty,
       case when sumtab.Rnk=1 then 
         (select variance(ReplenQty)
             from (select  sum(t1.OrdQty) as ReplenQty
                     from BeforeReplenQty t2 
               inner join BeforeReplenQty t1 
               where t2.part=t1.part and t2.customer=t1.customer
                 and t2.OrdDt between t1.StartDate and t1.ReplenDate 
               group by t1.Part,t1.Customer,t1.OrdDt,t1.OrdQty,t1.StartDate,t1.ReplenDate) t3) else 0 end as ReplenVar
from (
    select t1.*,sum(t1.OrdQty) as ReplenQty
     from BeforeReplenQty t2 
    inner join BeforeReplenQty t1 
    where t2.part=t1.part and t2.customer=t1.customer
      and t2.OrdDt between t1.StartDate and t1.ReplenDate 
    group by t1.Part,t1.Customer,t1.OrdDt,t1.OrdQty,t1.StartDate,t1.ReplenDate) tab
left join (select part,customer,orddt,rnk
from (
select t.part,t.customer,t.OrdDt,
@s:=CASE WHEN @c <> t.part THEN 1 ELSE @s+1 END AS rnk,
   @c:=t.part AS partSet
from (SELECT @s:= 0) s 
inner join (SELECT @c:= 'A') c 
inner join (SELECT * from BeforeReplenQty 
            order by Part, Customer, OrdDt) t
     ) tab
where rnk = 1
   ) sumtab
on tab.part=sumtab.part and tab.customer=sumtab.customer and tab.orddt=sumtab.orddt;
```

Comment: When I run the above code I get Error Code: 1267. Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '<>'